# Multilingual Datatype in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, schema

Can anyone tell me which data type i have to use to make my field multilingual ?

I have to give facility to user that they can use username in multiple language. Like,

Chinese, French, English, Hindi, Gujarati, Japanese etc.

I have to store user name in MYSQL database.

Comment: datatype and character  support  are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your collation to uft8_unicode_ci so you can account for Multilanguage characters.
There are other questions on the same subject i believe.

Here is a link to show you how to do it: http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8

Comment: What if i want to make only one field multilingual ?  uft8_unicode_ci  will create whole table multilingual is it so ?

Comment: Yeah it will. If you wan to convert just one column to utf8 check out this tutorial: http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/

Comment: After changing it to  uft8_unicode_ci if my column is like column_name varchar(45) will it allow multilingual data ?

Comment: uft8 treats multilanguage characters as characters NOT bytes so as long as you have less than 45 characters in your varchars you'll be ok. Spend some time and read the links that I gave you. They explain every detail. I think you will resolve any further questions you have that way.