# How to insert multilingual strings to database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, character-encoding

I read about NVARCHAR type, but there aren't any type named NVARCHAR in the phpmyadmin window of my free hosting server. (000webhost.com)

I can manually insert strings like 'തിരുവനന്തപുരം∙ മൂന്നു വർഷങ്ങൾക്കു മുൻപ് മൊയ്തീന്റെ കഥയുടെ വൺലൈൻ കേട്ടപ്പൊഴേ എന്ന് നിന്റെ മൊയ്തീൻ സിനിമ ചെയ്യാൻ തീരുമാനിച്ചിരുന്നു ' to database rows but when i use a php to do the same the inserted data becomes something like

&#3368 ;&#3405 ;&#3375 ;&#3394 ;&#3361 ;&#3453 ;&#3385 ;&#3391 ;&#8729 ; &#3335 ;&#3368 ;&#3405 ;&#3364 ;&#3405 ;&#3375 ;

i am using collation utf8_unicode_ci and type VARCHAR(1000) now.

my php code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$con = new mysqli("mysql1.000webhost.com", "a9798817_person",
"starting1", "a9798817_person");
$con->set_charset('utf8');


if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 


if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]["name"])&&!empty($_FILES["image3"]["name"]))
{

        echo"first second and third image with content is uploaded";
        $file_name1=$_FILES["image1"]["name"];
        $target_path1 = "images/".$file_name1;
        $temp_name1=$_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_name2=$_FILES["image2"]["name"];
        $target_path2 = "images/".$file_name2;
        $temp_name2=$_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_name3=$_FILES["image3"]["name"];
        $target_path3 = "images/".$file_name3;
        $temp_name3=$_FILES["image3"]["tmp_name"];

    $content="തിരുവനന്തപുരം∙ മൂന്നു വർഷങ്ങൾക്കു മുൻപ് മൊയ്തീന്റെ കഥയുടെ വൺലൈൻ കേട്ടപ്പൊഴേ എന്ന് നിന്റെ മൊയ്തീൻ സിനിമ ചെയ്യാൻ തീരുമാനിച്ചിരുന്നു "
    print($content);
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, $target_path1)&&move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, $target_path2)&&move_uploaded_file($temp_name3, $target_path3))
    {
    $query_upload="INSERT INTO MAINNEWS (image1,image2,image3,content) VALUES ('$file_name1','$file_name2','$file_name3','$content')"; 
    $con->query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());    
    }
    else
    {
    exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 
}
```

i get an output as

```
first second and third image with content is uploadedതിരുവനന്തപുരം∙ മൂന്നു വർഷങ്ങൾക്കു മുൻപ് മൊയ്തീന്റെ കഥയുടെ വൺലൈൻ കേട്ടപ്പൊഴേ എന്ന് നിന്റെ മൊയ്തീൻ സിനിമ ചെയ്യാൻ തീരുമാനിച്ചിരുന്നു
```

but in the database,, the content field is shown like

&#3368 ;&#3405 ;&#3375 ;&#3394 ;&#3361 ;&#3453 ;&#3385 ;&#3391 ;&#8729 ; etc

NOTE  : ACTUALLY THERE AREN'T ANY SPACES BETWEEN NUMBER AND ';' ,, I PUT IT INTENTIONALLY OTHERWISE THE IT DISPLAYS NORMALLY LIKE  ന്യൂഡൽഹി∙

Comment: That's HTML escaping, and it doesn't happen by itself. Somewhere `htmlentities()` is involved. If not at insertion time, then during display. Explain how you inspected the database content, or how it was retrieved and printed.

Comment: MySQL does not have NVARCHAR type (this one is for example in MSSQL). Anyway, check if string sent to databse is really the desired one - for example if connection configuration is right.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081934/multilingual-datatype-in-mysql

Comment: i jus opened my database and checked @mario

Comment: i am already using utf8_unicode_ci @Suyog

Comment: If you can't explain in more detail how you "checked" then this is neither reproducible and nor answerable without guessing. (PhpMyAdmin is completely unsuitable for debugging these kind of issues.)

Comment: @mario i opened my database and it looked like this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32QSOHq1eNZMHZUXzRGS1FfUnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That doesn't tell you anything about what's actually in the database.

Comment: u can see the value in column 'content' in first row.. right? it should be something like this തിരുവനന്തപുരം∙ മൂന്നു വർഷങ്ങൾക്കു മുൻപ് മൊയ്തീന്റെ കഥയുടെ വൺലൈൻ കേട്ടപ്പൊഴേ എന്ന് നിന്റെ മൊയ്തീൻ സിനിമ ചെയ്യാൻ തീരുമാനിച്ചിരുന്നു right? @mario

Comment: That's what PhpMyAdmin displays. What PhpMyAdmin *displays* is **not** the same things as what the database *contains*. Depends on lots of config settings. Why did you ignore the comment about not using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: when i retreive data from this database in an android app,, the text shows exactly as the same as in the pic (from 1st row)..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32QSOHq1eNZcDhZbURIVmUwUHM/view?usp=sharing

take a look at this pic @mario when i retreive data in android app from row 1,, it shows as numbers and symbols as in the pic,, but when retreived from row 2,, it shows exactly the non-english characters perfectly. NOTE: The second row is inserted manually

Comment: Your pictures *aren't relevant* unless you elaborate how data got there. (What you're specifically not letting on is this: one of the rows was inserted through above script, the other via PMA. And the latter garbled up the input.) - Again, you need to figure out what's going on. Guessing the problem won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This note contains some introductory explanations.

Some makes and models of rdbms table server use the `NVARCHAR()` data type to store unicode data. Unicode is a good way to store multiple-language data like, in your case, Sinhalese (correct?) and English.

But MySQL *does not have the `NVARCHAR()` data type*. Instead, you may, when creating columns in tables, specify the character set to use to store the contents. The UTF8 character set is good for this. You can also specify a collation (like `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_sinhala_ci`.  These collations *have no effect* on the way data is stored, only on how it is sorted and filtered.

MySQL (like all makes and models of table server) is a client-server system. The server holds the data and satisfies queries. You *must use a client* to insert or retrieve data from the server. The client handles your data on the way in and again on the way out.

Your question says you "manually inserted" some data into the server. Precisely speaking, that is entirely impossible. You must have used some client software, even if it was the mysql command line program. To solve your problem, you will need to figure out what client software you used for that so-called "manual" operation. Why? Because client software handles your data.

The program called `phpMyadmin` is one of those client programs. Unfortunately, it is very difficult to use for troubleshooting your kind of problem. Why? It uses a web browser to render its output.  The world contains many ways of representing multiple-language characters. Web browsers are built for users of information. They do their best to guess what a user would like to see.

In particular, Web browsers accept characters coded as HTML entities, and translate them for the viewer.  For example, `&lt;&amp;&gt` is rendered as **<&>**. And, your data string

```
&#3368;&#3405;&#3375;&#3394;&#3361;&#3453;&#3385;&#3391;&#8729;
```

renders as **ന്യൂഡൽഹി∙**.

(The people who built Stack Overflow went to a great deal of trouble to make sure we can show these literal html entities.)

Most Unicode characters can be represented as a 16-bit item, e.g. hex 3368 represents **ന**.   They also can be represented as these html entities: the hex number preceded by `&#` and followed by semicolon.  In a browser (that is, in phpmyadmin) you won't be able to tell the difference unless you use View Source...

This html entity stuff allows all kinds of information to be represented as a stream of 7-bit (ASCII, compatible with the old-school teletype machines) characters. It comes in handy for data interchange. But it doesn't work with MySQL collations.

So, here's the thing. The information in your database seems to have been encoded in the html entities form  (`&#3368;`) rather than in the unicode for Sinhalese. Your task is to figure out how that happened.

PHP programs can translate utf text to entitized text with `htmlentities()`.  Other languages have similar functions. It's clear that the software you used to put your data into MySQL did that.

That entitized text, once you've retrieved it from MySQL, can be translated back to unicode by `html_decode()`.

How can you figure out what's stored in MySQL? Try this:

```
 SELECT col, CHARACTER_LENGTH(col), HEX(col)
```

This will show the value of `col` presented by your client. It will also show the number of characters in the column and the hex coding of the col. The number of characters in an entitized character is six, whereas the number in the unicode character is one.

Comment: thank you sir for your time,, i will try your solution.. thanks for helping. :)

Comment: thank u.. it helped a lot. PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: You're welcome. Your language has beautiful letters!